# Phone number regex in javascript/jquery on (000)000-0000

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery.validate.addMethod(), and need a regex for specific phone number format. I somehow knew it before, but since I don't use regex that much, I forgot.

So, this is just a simple question: How do you create a regex for javascript on the following format:

(000)000-0000

The current phoneUS format which jQuery Validate possess is not applicable to the current problem.

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin already contains a rule for this format called `phoneUS`.  You may have to include the `additional-methods.js` file.

Comment: Did you see the question that I need specific phone number and not phoneUS? I can still use phoneUS... but just a specific format. It's both!

Comment: No, I do not see anything about `phoneUS` in your question.   Anyway, it was only meant as a helpful comment.

Comment: There is no need to put phoneUS in the question because the question does not relate to any phoneUS question because it is just the format. I'm just frustrated that some people don't understand the problem. But, thanks for the helpful comment. It helps answer the intent of the question.

Comment: Just because you asked for a regex does not mean we're supposed to know you already excluded the regex built into the plugin which allows this same format along with some variations.   Nor are you the only person who could ever possibly benefit from reading my first comment.  It's just frustrating when people can't write well enough to clearly explain the intent of the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^\(\d{3}\)\s?\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

This allows for a space after the closing parenthesis as well.

Comment: You may want to validate a cleaned version instead by removing all spaces, parenthesis, and dashes. That way you could support a flat format or a 000 000-0000 format.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
/^\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```